# Exporting a Table into HTML Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, export

I'm trying to export a table into HTML, all while keeping the styling intact.

This is a table similar to the one I'm trying to export:
[image]
I think I'm not that far from the solution but I'm still having trouble processing each row.

Here's what I have done so far:

```
exportHTMLFile: function (object) {

    var processRow = function (row, title) {
        var finalVal = '';
        // row processing goes here    <----------
        return finalVal;
    };

    const {filename, table} = object;
    var htmlFile = '<table>';
    for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
        htmlFile += processRow(table[i], i === 0);
    }
    htmlFile += '</table>';
    htmlFile = new Blob([htmlFile], {type: 'text/html;charset=utf-8'});
    var downloadHTML;
    downloadHTML = document.createElement('a');
    downloadHTML.download = filename;
    downloadHTML.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(htmlFile);
    downloadHTML.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(downloadHTML);
    downloadHTML.click();
    document.body.removeChild(downloadHTML);
}
```

What I need to do now is:

1. Figure out how to create a HTML model similar to the aforementioned example.
2. Alternate the gray and white color for the rows depending on the row number (odd of even).
3. Make a loop to populate the table

Do you guys have an idea how I can proceed for this?

**EDIT**: 
I finally got it to work, but now I'm having a problem alternating colors between rows.

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined
```

Which is bizarre given that table[i] is not empty, and the error is being thrown by the word `style` in the following line:

```
table[i].style.backgroundColor = 'gray';
```

Here's how the full function looks like now:

```
exportHTMLFile: function (object) {
    var processRow = function (row,title) {
        var htmlString = '<tr>';
        for (var i = 0, len = row.length; i < len; i++) {
            htmlString += '<td>' + row[i] + '</td>';
        }
        htmlString += '</tr>';
        return htmlString;
    };
    const {filename, table} = object;
    var htmlFile = '<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%"><tr><td valign="MIDDLE"><p align="LEFT">';
    for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
        htmlFile += processRow(table[i], i===0);
        if(i%2==0){
            table[i].style.backgroundColor = 'gray';
        }else{
            table[i].style.backgroundColor = 'none';
        }
    }
    htmlFile += '</table>';
    htmlFile = new Blob([htmlFile], {type: 'text/html;charset=utf-8'});
    var downloadHTML;
    downloadHTML = document.createElement('a');
    downloadHTML.download = filename;
    downloadHTML.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(htmlFile);
    downloadHTML.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(downloadHTML);
    downloadHTML.click();
    document.body.removeChild(downloadHTML);

}
```

Comment: 1. That looks like a regular HTMl table; 2. Use CSS pseudo selectors, :nth-of-type(2n+1) & :nth-of-type(2n) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type; 3. that is basic JS, use a for, forEach, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let content = {
  1: ["this is", "a cool", "table"],
  2: ["this is", "another cool", "table"],
  3: ["this is", " a crazy cool", "table..."],
  4: ["this is", " a crazy cool", "table..."],
}


for (let i in content) {
  $("#table").append(`<div style="margin-top: ${i*4}%" class="row">
                        <div style="background: ${!(i%2) ? "gray" : "none"}" class="col colA">${content[i][0]}</div>
                        <div style="background: ${!(i%2) ? "gray" : "none"}" class="col colB">${content[i][1]}</div>
                        <div style="background: ${!(i%2) ? "gray" : "none"}" class="col colC">${content[i][2]}</div>
                      </div>`);
}
```

```css
#table {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: gray;
}

.row {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0%;
  background: gray;
}

.col {
  background: gray;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  
}
.colA {
  left: 0%;
  width: 15%;
}

.colB {
  left: 15%;
  width: 50%;
}

.colC {
  left: 65%;
  width: 35%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col colA"><b>Date</b></div>
    <div class="col colB"><b>Type</b></div>
    <div class="col colC"><b>Message</b></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did this answer helped you?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both jonas and Erick for their time and answers. I had to take a different approach though and use a pure JS solution. Here's how the processRow function looks like now:

```
var processRow = function (row,title) {
    var htmlString = '<tr>';
    for (var i = 0, len = row.length; i < len; i++) {
        htmlString += '<td>' + row[i] + '</td>';
    }
    htmlString += '</tr>';
    return htmlString;
};
```

There's only one small problem; the output looks like this:
[image]
There's an empty row at the beginning which I really don't where it's coming from.